# Determining whenever user checks or unchecks a checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("input[type='checkbox'][name='mycheckboxname']").change(function () {
        if ($(this).checked == true) {
            //do something (script 1)
        }
        else {
            //do something else (script 2)
        }
    })
});
```

What i want to accomplish is to have 2 scripts running depening whenever user checks or unchecks a "mycheckboxname" checkbox.
Problem is that with above code i get always only script 2 to run so it looks like `if $(this).checked` is always `false` even if user checks the `checkbox`. Am I using `$(this)` the wrong way?

Comment: Try $(this).prop('checked')

Comment: `this.checked` without $ sign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`checked` is a DOM property of the element, but `$(this)` returns a jQuery object.

You could just use the DOM property:

```
if (this.checked)
```

There's no reason to wrap `this` in a jQuery instance for that. I mean, you *can*:

```
if ($(this).prop("checked"))
```

...but it doesn't do anything useful on top of `this.checked`.

---

Side note:

```
if (someBoolean == true)
```

is just a roundabout way of writing

```
if (someBoolean)
```

I mean, why stop there? Why not

```
if ((someBoolean == true) == true)
```

or

```
if (((someBoolean == true) == true) == true)
```

or... ;-)

Comment: A+ for taking the extra effort to teach people that jQuery isn't always necessary. Xo.

Comment: learned for this usage of `if ($(this).prop("checked"))` and deleted my answer

Comment: yea this is what I was looking for. I don't know why I was so sure it was a "this" targeting wrong object. Thanks for extended answer in side note - I'll remember to use it this way now.

Answer (score 2):

Use `$(this).prop("checked")` to get the `true`/`false` value of a `<input type="checkbox">`

Click the **run code snippet** below to see it work

---

```js
$("input[type=checkbox]").change(function(event) {
  if ($(this).prop("checked") === true) {
    alert("ON");
  }
  else {
    alert("OFF");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox">click it
```

Comment: Or, you know, `this.checked`. There's no reason whatsoever for `$(this).prop("checked")`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder ^.^ I am aware, yes, but I figure once you're in jQuery land, you might as well use jQuery idioms. If this was a vanilla JS answer, I certainly would've used `this.checked`. (Hope you're doing well ^.^)